# C# - What are the advantages of using overloads?

Tags: c#, overloading

Are there really any significant advantages to overload methods?

Let's consider the following example:

```
class SillyMath
{
    public static int Plus(int number1, int number2)
    {
        return Plus(number1, number2, 0);
    }

    public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3)
    {
        return Plus(number1, number2, number3, 0);
    }

    public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4)
    {
        return number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
    }
}
```

Wouldn't it be easier to just use parameters with default values?

```
public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3 = 0, int number4 = 0)
        {
            return number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
        }
```

**1. So can anyone tell me why would I bother considering overloads when programming?**

**2. And what if I need to throw in some conditional statements? Would overloading still be relevant?**

**EDIT: Also, meanwhile I learned that overloads can also have different return types. In my opinion that is something that makes overloads worthy of consideration.**

Comment: Why don't you use this case: `public static int Plus(params int[] number)`. I think it should be better?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would be better. But what if the parameters are of different types?

Comment: Named and Optional arguments in C# are a recent thing; also, by baking a default value in, and not letting the caller decide, you are adding a constraint to the interface - what if, in the future, you needed to change that value? All callers relying on the old behaviour would have to change.

Comment: Yes, but if the default value doesn't change the output in any way, why would I need to change it later? Isn't that the point of using default values? The caller always gets something when leaving default values in and it gets something else when altering the default values. I'm getting extremely confused...

Comment: Trite example, but imagine if rather than 0, your default was then one, for some reason. Anyone calling your interface would then find their result was now 2 more than they might expect.

Comment: I think I get you. Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason might be to make what appears to be a single method that takes a variety of different inputs. For example, `BinaryWriter.Write` having the following overloads (and a couple others):

```
Write(Boolean)
Write(Byte) 
Write(Byte[])   
Write(Char) 
Write(Char[])   
Write(Decimal)  
Write(Double)   
Write(Int16)    
Write(Int32)    
Write(Int64)    
Write(SByte)    
Write(Single)   
Write(String)   
Write(UInt16)   
Write(UInt32)   
Write(UInt64)
```

Allowing you to write code like:

```
bool   value1 = true;
int    value2 = 5;
double value3 = 5.5;
byte   value4 = 1;

using (BinaryWriter writer = GetABinaryWriter())
{
   writer.Write(value1);
   writer.Write(value2);
   writer.Write(value3);
   writer.Write(value4);
}
```

Comment: Wow, yeah, that's adding some extra value to overloads! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*Overloads* exist much before then parameters with default values comes present in `C#`, but

> So can anyone tell me why would I bother considering overloads when programming?

If the diversity of parameters tends to be big (i's a subjective, but **I** would say more then 5), it's better to use `overload`s, as it's easier to read a code.

> And what if I need to throw in some conditional statements? Would overloading still be relevant?

Don't **really** get what you're asking for, but I *suppose*, you mean throw exception based on different parameters values.

This is a really good example where it's better to use overloads, to localize decisional logic in every overloaded function and not in `if/elseif/else` or `switch/case` in one big single method.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

What in regard of your last comment about `number3`.

I would think about something like this:

```
///
///<int number3>A number for something not more then default value </int number3> //COMMENT
public void function(int number3Maximum = 100) //MAKE ESPLICIT EXPECTED MAXIMUM VALUE
{
   if(number3Maximum >100)
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("number3Maximum can not be more then default maximum"); 

     ..... //CODE
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me in an edited answer how would you rewrite the overloads code block if I wanted to add number3 only if number3 is less than 100 ? May be a silly question, but I would like to see how you think the code should look then.

Comment: I see. but what I wanted to know is how would overloads help in dealing with that condition. I could throw the ArgumentOutOfRangeException in the public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3 = 0, int number4 = 0) method as well. I asked about that condition because you said that conditions are a good example to use overloads.

Comment: @IneedHelp: I mean, in case when you have *overloads* this exception will appear **only** in that method and not in others, as the `number3` parameter is present **only** there.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now. Thanks a lot of your time and help! And a big thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

I'll prefer explaining in your language

```
class SillyMath
    {
        public static int Plus(int number1, int number2)
        {
            return Plus(number1, number2, 0);
        }

        public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3)
        {
            return Plus(number1, number2, number3, 0);
        }

        public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4)
        {
            return number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
        }
    }
```

Now suppose there are two users A and B;

> A's requirement is to add two numbers 43 & 45
>
> B's requirement is to add three numbers 123, 98 & 63

If we were to use two argumented function i.e. int

```
Plus(int number1, int number2)
```

then B had been writing codes like `Plus(123,Plus(98,63));`

Similarly for three argumented function A's code had been `Plus(43,45,0);`

Now you can see both code looks dirty from some point of view.
So sometimes to facilitate programmers overloaded functions are implemented which adds extra customization features to the task.

An example

```
  MessageBox.Show("You must enter a name.", "Name Entry Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

You can use MessageBox without 
 `"Name Entry Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation` and only thing you will miss, is the customization and things will come up in default form.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what I still don't understand is how is this better than using parameters with default values?

A's code could be written as Plus(43, 45) because 0 is the default value of the 3rd parameter.

Comment: <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.100)">MessageBox.Show </a>function is a better example for this question. :)

Comment: Ok, let's say that in the message box example the 3rd and 4th parameters have default values that do not have any effect on the final output unless they are given values by the caller. How is that any different. I do not want to be an annoyance, I just want to understand how things work.

Comment: Thats why we have overloading,if a parameter is not required then skip it, else increase passed parameters till it gets close to requirement.

Comment: So would you conclude that overloads' only purpose is to improve code readability and method management?

Comment: readability is secondary, more is the method management/enhancement..

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Thumbs up, and I will wait to see what Tigran can add, then I will chose one of the two answers.

Comment: @IneedHelp: A method which accepts optional parameters may be called with any combination of them being present or absent.  In many cases, this doesn't really make sense.  Frequently, functions will have certain parameters that must be specified or omitted as a group, and they will have certain parameters which cannot be included with certain others.  The default-parameter mechanisms offer no way to specify such limitations.

Comment: @supercat:- Oh the great supercat from electrical engineering is here!!!...its hard to find some one so exceptional like you... :thumbsup: :)